# How can I get all of the Twitter updates ever made by a user?

Tags: twitter

This is really just for my own use: I would like to be able to search all of my updates, ever.  Twitter's search (http://search.twitter.com) is time-limited - it only seems to search the last few weeks of updates, so it is difficult to find something I had posted months ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of messages from a user you can use Twitter API but you'll need a user & password for some of the calls like the one you need:

Example for a max of 200:
[http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=200](http://twitter.com/statuses/USERNAMEHERE_timeline.xml?count=200)

You can use other parameters like "since" or other formats differents to XML. [Click here for more info](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation)

Comment: I just tried this, but Twitter's response is an error in the XML file saying "Not Found".  Do I need to setup the Twitter API for my account somehow?

Comment: Hmm, so it looks like this just uses my logged-in user if I request http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=200

Thanks for the tip!  Could you edit the URL in your answer to reflect that?

Comment: Done. user_timeline.xml is now the example URL

Answer (score 2):

First, you must be authorized to view the user account (otherwise you will never get the user's whole timeline). There are two ways to achieve authentication: you can either log in with the user's credentials or acquire an OAuth authentication token. The OAuth method is definitely the way to go, there is almost never a good reason to use the actual credentials and users are weary of supplying their login data to random applications.

Once you have the OAuth token, you can make a call to the REST API to get the user's timeline with

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.format
```

Where *format* stands for the preferred output format your application digests (right now xml, json, rss and atom are supported).

Besides the obvious *user_id* parameter, the *count* and *page* parameters are important for your purposes. *count* allows you to specify how many results you would like to get back (up to 200) and *page* is for the page number you would like to get back. All in all, you can get the last 3200 updates for any given user (for any combination of *count* x *page*).

To avoid unnecessary crawling, your application should contact the Twitter API for current statuses a few times a day in the background. Be aware that there are per-user limits on how often you can make queries to the Twitter server so local caching of status messages is a must.

Use the search API only if you absolutely must. For your scenario it's almost certainly not warranted.

You can find the API documentation for the statuses/user_timeline call [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-user_timeline). And an excellent PHP module for OAuth/Twitter is available from Abraham Williams via [github](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master).

Comment: The OAuth method is still buggy... For example if our company used OAuth we would have had a broken application for close to 70 hours. Id wait a bit until twitter gets their shit straightened out.

Comment: Generally, there is no excuse for using a person's actual credentials to log in. I know, Facebook does it with GMail and so on, but it's still a security nightmare. And that's exactly what OAuth solves. Twitter outages come in all forms and shapes, but that's no reason to prefer a direct login in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

heres a trick

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.xml?count=1000&since=0
```

the since param allows you to override the default count max :) so now you can get a ton of updates without having to traverse pages.